# Aramaic compared to Spanish

Tags: spanish, aramaic

Is it possible to compare Aramaic to Spanish? If so, what are the differences and what are common? I have Spanish at school, and when I saw Passion of the Christ, I recognized lots of words (I don't remember them now, unfortunately, I just noticed during the film). Is it only the vocabulary that is a bit common, or does the grammar also have things in common?

I'm looking for the lexicon, grammar and word-endings mostly, a comparison between the languages.

Comment: Hello 50ndr33 and welcome to the Linguistics site. Can you expand a bit? For example, what words did you recognize? And what kind of comparison are you looking for? Grammar? Lexicon? No need to answer to me here, you can directly edit the question and add/re-word it. :)

Comment: @Alenanno Done!

Comment: Just to be clear, most of the dialog in *Passion of the Christ* is in Aramaic, but some is in Latin (particularly when the Romans are involved).

Comment: Latin was also used in the film. Perhaps you refer to the part where Jesus speaks to Pilate in Latin or when Mary Magdalene speaks Latin to the Roman soldiers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aramaic and Spanish are of entirely different language families: Semitic (a branch of Afroasiatic) and Romance (a branch of Indo-European), respectively. I am not aware of much contact between the two languages, so it is unlikely that one borrowed words or constructions from the other.

What you heard in the film was most likely Latin, the ancestor of all the Romance languages, like Spanish, Italian, French, Portuguese, and Romanian. And Latin's daughter languages still resemble her a great deal, especially with respect to vocabulary. Notice also how many words English has borrowed from French and Latin: you should be able to recognise various words you know in English when you hear Latin, like *entirely, different, language, family,* etc (Latin *integer, differens, lingua, familia*).

Comment: Yes, I remember "veritas". Even though that isn't Aramaic but Latin.

Comment: @50ndr33: Yes, exactly. In vino veritas!

Comment: Note that Aramaic is a language family, as wide as Romance (even 'old' or biblical-era Aramaic is a language family with this amount of variance), Proto-Semitic, is as wide and probably contemporary with Proto-Indo-European. (round 3750-BCE is often quoted) - while the very theoretical proto-afro-asiatic is from around 11000BCE if at all. This is a common misconception in scale.

Answer (score 6):

Spanish was heavily influenced by the Arabic language during the [11th through 13th centuries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_language_influence_on_the_Spanish_language#History). Modern Spanish has [several hundred loan words taken from Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_language_influence_on_the_Spanish_language#List_of_words_of_Arabic_origin) used in common vocabulary. *Almohada* is probably the most famous (meaning "pillow").

Modern [Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_language) is related to Semitic languages such as ancient [Aramaic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramaic).

So there is some connection between Spanish and Aramaic. But it's not a very strong connection; not one a casual listener would likely ever notice.